# Faster way to set a RichTextBox text in TextChanged event to another Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

I'm working in a program which allows real time editing, using RTboxes in readonly mode to show text.

I order to make it easy to write/read text I made this custom element class:

```
    public class Texts : RichTextBox
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange tr;

        public Texts()
        {
            //_RtStylish is a class I made to create all the Brushes, Bitmaps and fonts stuff. It's kind of long to do this for each one so I implemented it to just write a simple line with my class.
            Background = _RtStylish._tr_cl;
            Foreground = _RtStylish._stdCl;

            BorderThickness = _RtStylish.t_flat;
            Width = 100;
            Height = 30;
            FontFamily = _RtStylish._font("Arial");
            FontSize = 40;
            Document = fd;
        }

        public void _text(string txt)
        {
            p.Inlines.Add(txt);
            fd.Blocks.Add(p);
//To add text I just write RichTextBox._text("Something");
        }



        public string _readText()
        {
            tr = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
            return tr.Text;
        }
//This returns a string with the text inside the RTbox

        public void _Cleartxt()
        {
            p.Inlines.Clear();
            fd.Blocks.Clear();
            p.Inlines.Add("");
            fd.Blocks.Add(p);
        }
//Clears my box

        public void _alignment(int n)
        {
            switch (n) 
            { 
                case 0:
            fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            break;
                case 1:
            fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;
            break;
                case 2:
            fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
            break;
                case 3:
            fd.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
            break;
            }
        }


    }
```

The problem is that I have a second Window which is a scaled copy of the real one and allows to change the text in the RTboxes for Real Time editing. So what I did was this event and give it to all the rich boxes:

```
  private void _text(Object o, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_Tmod.IsFocused)
        {
            _title._Cleartxt();
            _title._text(_Tmod._readText());
        }
        else if(_Qmod.IsFocused)
        {
            _question._Cleartxt();
            _question._text(_Qmod._readText());
        }
        else if(_Amod.IsFocused)
        {
            _ans._Cleartxt();
            _ans._text(_Amod._readText());
        }

    }
```

If I don't clear the textbox it will leave the old text += new text. For example, If I have this in the main window text: "Hellowww" and then I modify it by the RTbox editor and add a "a" it shows: "HellowHellowa" so I have to Clear the Box.

It works fine but when the user types text in the editor's one it is kind of laggy when it show in the main window. I think this happens because I'm clearing the Box doccument and the adding a new block everytime I change text. Is there a faster way to assign the text of a textbox to another when changed?

In WinForms it would be just like `TextBox1.Text = EditorTextbox.Text;` and there is not lagg. By lagg I mean it takes some pauses between writing a long text. Even though, it does not miss any character but I don't like the program to look laggy :(

Any improved way to do this like in WinForms?

Comment: Have you considered data binding?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) to do what you want if you use [A Bindable WPF RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66054/A-Bindable-WPF-RichTextBox). If you want the same text to appear in two `TextBox`es, then you could just bind the same `FlowDocument` property to the `Document`property on both `RichTextBox`es:

```
<Prefix:BindableRichTextBox Name="TextBox1" Document="{Binding YourProperty}" />
...
<Prefix:BindableRichTextBox Name="TextBox2" Document="{Binding YourProperty}" />
```

If you want to show an edited version of the text, then you could add another property which edits the text:

```
public FlowDocument YourProperty
{
    get { return yourProperty; }
    set
    {
        yourProperty = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("YourProperty");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("YourEditedProperty");
    }
}

public FlowDocument YourEditedProperty
{
    get { return SomeManipulationMethod(YourProperty); }
}
```

...

```
<Prefix:BindableRichTextBox Name="TextBox1" Document="{Binding YourProperty}" />
...
<Prefix:BindableRichTextBox Name="TextBox2" Document="{Binding YourEditedProperty}" />
```